# Systemd Loader - Windows Has No Configuration File

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, systemd

I am currently trying to duel boot Windows 10 and Pop-OS. Pop-OS and Windows 10 are on separate drives and I am using Systemd as my boot loader. To get Windows to show on my boot loader I added the Windows files bootmfg.efi and bootmgr.efi into Boot/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/ on my boot drive (the one with Pop-OS and my Systemd bootloader). After doing this Windows shows up and I can select it in my boot-loader on startup.

The problem is that if I select that option I will get an error telling me that I have a corrupted or missing configuration file. I looked into Boot/EFI/Loader/entries/ and I found Pop_OS-current.conf Pop_OS-oldkern.conf and Recovery-DD&C-878b.conf. Do I need a .conf file for windows in here and if so what would that look like?

I know the format for the other .conf files goes something like this

- title
- linux
- initrd
- options

I thought about trying to replicate this but I have no idea what I would populate these categories with. Am I on the right track or am I totally off on how to accomplish this?